# Visualforce error - 'the markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed'

Tags: visualforce

I am looking at the final Visualforce page example from [here](http://www.verticalcoder.com/2014/11/21/datatables-in-visualforce-part-1/). I have saved the controller with no issue but upon trying to save the VF page, I am returning this error on line 56: 'the markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed'. Line 56 is this part:

```
</apex:page><apex:page Controller="DataTableExampleController" readOnly="true">
```

I don't understand what the problem is? Can someone advise?

```
<apex:page Controller="DataTableExampleController" readOnly="true">
    <head>
        <apex:includescript value="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" / >
        <apex:includescript value="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" />
        <apex:stylesheet value="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
        <script>
            j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
            j$(document).ready( function () {
                var contactTable = j$('[id$="contacttable"]').DataTable({
                    order: [[2, 'asc']],

                    initComplete: function() {
                        var api = this.api();
                        var select = j$('[id$=accountSelect]');
                        api.column(0).data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                            select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                        } );   
                    }
                });

                j$('[id$=accountSelect]').change(function() {
                    var val = j$.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        j$(this).val()
                    );
                    contactTable.column(0)
                        .search( val == 'All' ? '' : '^'+val+'$', true, false )
                        .draw();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="accountSelect"><option value="All">All</option></select>

        <table id="contacttable" class="display">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Account</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <apex:repeat value="{!contactList}" var="contact">
                    <tr>
                        <td>{!contact.Account.Name}</td>
                        <td>{!contact.FirstName}</td>
                        <td>{!contact.LastName}</td>
                        <td>{!contact.Phone}</td>
                    </tr>
                </apex:repeat>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</apex:page><apex:page Controller="DataTableExampleController" readOnly="true">
    <head>
        <apex:includescript value="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" / >
        <apex:includescript value="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" />
        <apex:stylesheet value="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />
        <script>
            j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
            j$(document).ready( function () {
                var contactTable = j$('[id$="contacttable"]').DataTable({
                    order: [[2, 'asc']],

                    initComplete: function() {
                        var api = this.api();
                        var select = j$('[id$=accountSelect]');
                        api.column(0).data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                            select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                        } );   
                    }
                });

                j$('[id$=accountSelect]').change(function() {
                    var val = j$.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                        j$(this).val()
                    );
                    contactTable.column(0)
                        .search( val == 'All' ? '' : '^'+val+'$', true, false )
                        .draw();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="accountSelect"><option value="All"></option></select>

        <table id="contacttable" class="display">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Account</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <apex:repeat value="{!contactList}" var="contact">
                    <tr>
                        <td>{!contact.Account.Name}</td>
                        <td>{!contact.FirstName}</td>
                        <td>{!contact.LastName}</td>
                        <td>{!contact.Phone}</td>
                    </tr>
                </apex:repeat>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Your code contains two `<apex:page> </apex:page>`.

Comment: This page code is working correctly @Andy Hitchings. That website code is pasted in double time. In the same mistake having your page. Please remove Line 56 `<apex:page ... >` upto `</apex:page>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using :

```
</apex:page><apex:page Controller="DataTableExampleController" readOnly="true">
```

second time in your code. I think you have pasted code two times. Please check.

Comment: I have flagged this answer as not being an answer. This would be better suited as a comment or maybe an edit to the original post. Thanks.

Comment: @cmmoutes13 But this is an answer? OP has used two `<apex:page>` tags which would throw this error.

Comment: Or there is the possibility that they only did that will posting the question on here. Therefore I believe it is better suited as a comment until that is addressed by the OP.

Comment: Oh alright, I realize what you are saying now. I will remove the flag. Apologies.

Comment: @cmmoutes13 Look at the link; the code indeed uses apex:page twice.